# Negate epsilon-delta continuity

Tags: real-analysis, logic

How can we come to the statement where $f$ is discontinuous at point $x_{0}$, when we know epsilon-delta proof:

$\forall {\epsilon}> 0 \: \:  \exists \delta _{\epsilon}> 0 \; : \left | x-x_{0} \right |< \delta _{\epsilon} \Rightarrow \left | f\left ( x \right )-f\left ( x_{0} \right ) \right |< \epsilon $

I believe we should get something like this:

$\left | x-x_{0} \right |< \delta _{\epsilon} \Rightarrow \left | f\left ( x \right )-f\left ( x_{0} \right ) \right |f\geq  \epsilon $

but i don't know how to come to this point using logical operators.

Comment: The negation of $\forall$ is $\exists \lnot$; thus, $\lnot \forall \epsilon > 0 \ \exists \delta > 0 \ldots$ will be ; $\exists \epsilon > 0 \ \forall \delta > 0 \lnot \ldots$.

Comment: For the "propositional" part, we have that $\lnot (p \to q)$ is equivalent to : $p \land \lnot q$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $f:D\subset \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be your function and $x_0\in D$. The formula for the continuity of $f$ in $x_0$ is: $$\forall  \varepsilon > 0 \ \ \  \exists \delta > 0 \ \ \ \forall x\in D  \ \ \ \left( |x-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon \right).$$

The negation is:

$$\exists  \varepsilon > 0 \ \ \  \ \forall \delta > 0 \ \ \ \ \exists x\in D  \ \ \ \left( |x-x_0|< \delta \wedge |f(x)-f(x_0)|\geq\varepsilon \right).$$

So, the standard rule is: When negating a first-order formula you "invert" the quantifiers without changing their domain and as $a\Rightarrow b$ is the same as $\neg a\vee b$ you have that $\neg (a\Rightarrow b)$ is the same as $a\wedge \neg b$ by applying De Morgan's Law.